# Overriding the + operator for certain types

Tags: haskell

I have the following type definition:

```
data NumList n = NumList [Rational]
```

Then in my code I define some NumLists like so,

```
n1 = NumList [1, 2, 3]
n2 = NumList [4, 5, 6]
```

What I would like to do is this:

```
n3 = n1 + n2 -- Should be [5, 7, 9]
```

I tried defining this as so:

```
toList :: NumList n -> [Rational]
toList (NumList n) = n

(+) :: NumList -> NumList -> NumList
(+) x y = if length x == length y
          then
              zipWith (+) toList x toList y -- This probably isn't right, but I'll debug this later
          else
              error "NumLists must be same length to add"
```

The error I get is:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `+'
It could refer to either `NumList.+',
                             defined at NumList.hs:7:5
                          or `Prelude.+'
```

I don't see how this is ambiguous since Prelude.+ applies to the `Num` class and NumList.+ only applies to the NumList type. Any guidance on this? Also a little bonus question: Is there a way to use pattern matching to remove the if expression from the (+) function?

Comment: Side note: you ask for `NumList` to have a type parameter, but don't use it. This can be useful, but given that you seem to be pretty much a beginner, it's probably not what you want. You might like either `data NumList = NumList [Rational]` or `data NumList n = NumList [n]` instead. Additionally, this is the canonical use case for `newtype` over `data`: when there's only one constructor and only one field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error right now is that there are 2 types of `(+)`s defined, one for Prelude and yours. You can fix this by making `NumList` an instance of the `Num` type.

```
instance Num NumList where
  (+) nl1 nl2 = implementPlus
  (*) nl1 nl2 = implementTimes
  (-) nl1 nl2 = implementMinus
  abs nl = NumList (map abs (toList nl))
  signum nl = NumList (map signum (toList nl))
  fromInteger i = NumList [fromInteger i]
```

Now addition will call `implemenPlus` and everything will be wonderful. As an added bonus, you can even write numeric literals, haskell will infer that they're a `NumList` and turn them into a list of one element, quite nice for writing lots of them.

Also, for your bonus question, I'd just write it like this

```
(NumList n1) + (NumList n2) = NumList $ zipWith (+) n1 n2
```

This is what I'd expect using it, that the result is the length of the shortest list. If you really want it to blow up,

```
 (NumList n1) + (NumList n2) |length n1 == length n2 =
                                NumList $ zipWith (+) n1 n2
                             | otherwise             = 
                                error "You done goofed"
```

This just uses guards, think of them as souped up `if`s. And `otherwise` is simply defined as

```
otherwise = True
```

in prelude.

Comment: That's awesome. Quick question though. Will map work directly on NumList, or will I have to do `abs n1 = map abs toList n1`?

Comment: Ah good catch, you'd have to unwrap it. I've edited to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on using guards and the shortened + function. What is the purpose of `$` in `NumList $ zipWith (+) n1 n2`?

Comment: @Max It's the same as `NumList (zipWith (+) n1 n2)`. It's just defined as `($) f a = f a` with a super low precedence so you don't have to write so many parens

Comment: @jozefg Wouldn't you have to wrap it again as well?

Comment: @kqr after my compilation failed, the answer is yes.